# 2 submit buttons in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, formtastic

I have a question about forms. I have a fairly standard form that saves a post (called an eReport in my app) with a title and body. The table also has a "published" field, which is boolean. The saved eReport only shows on the public site if this field is set to true, with false being the default.

Rather than the default check box, I would like to display two buttons at the end of the form: a "Publish Now" button and a "Save as Draft" button. If the user presses the former, the published field would be set to true. If the latter, then false. In PHP, I used to display 2 submit fields with different name values, then handle the input with an if/else statement to determine the proper SQL query to build. In Rails, I'm assuming I would place this logic in the controller, under the appropriate action, but I'm not sure how to manipulate the name or id values of buttons.

For the record, I'm using Formtastic, but if someone could show me how to do this with the default Rails form tags, that's OK too. Here's the code for my form as it stands right now:

```
<% semantic_form_for @ereport do |form| %>

  <% form.inputs do %>
    <%= form.input :title %>
    <%= form.input :body %>
  <% end %>
  <% form.buttons do %>
    <%= form.commit_button :label => "Publish Now" %>
<%= form.commit_button :label => "Save as Draft" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't know about formtastic, but with the default rails form builder, you could do it like this:

```
<%= form.submit "Save with option A", :name => "save_option_a" %>
<%= form.submit "Save with option B", :name => "save_option_b" %>
```

Then in the controller, you can pick those up in params:

```
if params[:save_option_a]
  # do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition to @iddlefingers answer, here is a view of the log of the application (striping some useless params due to explanation purposes)

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", ..., "comentar"=>"Confirmar"}
```

where we can see that `comentar` is the name of the parameter, and `"Confirmar"` is it's value, which is the button's text too.

which was obtained by `submit_tag "Confirmar", :name => 'comentar'`

So in general you could have (if you want to reduce the number of `params` you are working with) several `submit_tag "onevalue", :name => 'SAMEname'`, `submit_tag "othervalue", :name => 'SAMEname'`...

and retrieve them in your controller

```
if params[:SAMEname] == "onevalue"
# do stuff
elsif params[:SAMEname] == "othervalue"
#do different stuff
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use jQuery.
You can bind the button click event and submit the form for specified location.

Comment: Just starting to learn jQuery these days, but I'll keep it in mind. Thanks!