# Method for Button in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button, controller

I'm working on a forum app in Ruby on Rails and I would like to have two post buttons for comments; one button will post a comment along with one picture, the other will post a comment with a different picture.  The issue is that im not too sure how to go about doing this.  any suggestions?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272013/2-submit-buttons-in-a-form

Comment: Did you already try something? Do you have some code snippet to show?

Answer (score 0):

You could always have a radio button selector to pick which image gets posted with the comment, that would probably be the easiest. Checkout the simple form gem. https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation to `button_to` for the Rails framework:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to